# Remove jetty version in embedded Jetty in ActiveMQ

Tags: security, jetty, activemq-classic

We have not seen anywhere in the documentation of ActiveMQ how to hide the embedded jetty version. This is marked as a security thread by our penetration testers when we are using a web sockets transport on port 80. We have been playing around with the configuration file jetty.xml and the parameters, but no success. It has been addressed for other projects (see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-13414) by a patch in the code,

So far we have been trying to change the configuration in jetty.xml.

After searching for jetty properties, this is how we configured the property for the property:

```xml
<bean id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
  <property name="sendServerVersion" value="false">
  </property>
</bean>
```

However, this has no effect in the exposing of the version. We tried further with a connection factory, but this also had no effect:

```xml
<bean id="invokeConnectors" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="Server" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="setConnectors" />
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <constructor-arg ref="Server" />
        <constructor-arg>
        <list>
          <bean id="httpConnectionFactory"       class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
            <constructor-arg ref="httpConfig"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
      </constructor-arg>

<!-- see the jettyPort bean -->
<property name="host" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.host']}" />
<property name="port" value="#{systemProperties['jetty.port']}" />
</bean>

    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Are we on the right track, or does it need to be addressed by the codebase of ActiveMQ?

This is how we show the version:

```
#nmap -sV -p80 localhost
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-04-23 18:16 CEST
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000098s latency).

PORT STATE SERVICE VERSION
80/tcp open http Jetty 9.2.22.v20170606

Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 11.34 seconds
```

**Edit:** we received an answer in the [ActiveMQ JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-6951) that indicates that **it will need some code modification** in the ActiveMQ project. We will update this question if the current state changes. Current ActiveMQ is 5.15.3.

Quoting Tim Bain from the linked issue:

> Since org.apache.activemq.transport.discovery.http.EmbeddedJettyServer.start() creates its Server by calling new (no Spring injection), and the code of that method doesn't provide any means to specify an HttpConfiguration, the ability to change this behavior requires a code change. There is similar code in org.apache.activemq.transport.WebTransportServerSupport, also without any ability to specify an HttpConfiguration that would disable the sending of the version number.

Answer (score 2):

The use of ...

```java
org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration.setSendServerVersion(false);
```

... is the correct setting.

However, you cannot change this AFTER the server has been started.

The startup of the server itself, is the only place you can make this change.

When the Connectors are created/initialized is the only place this setting is used.

This is because that setting is propagated into many components during startup (the Http/1 Generator, the Http/2 Generator, the ErrorPage generator, the WebSocket Upgrade process, etc)

Comment: Thank you Joakim for your comment. We tried all combinations we could to have the parameters passed to the server, but coud not make it work. We got an answer in the AMQ JIRA indicating that the server is called without spring injection. Seems it needs some code change in the ActiveMQ project. I will add an edit to the question to clarify.